# Linked List sort method gives StackOverFlow Error during recursion, and comparing elements in the list

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, linked-list

I created Linked List from scratch, and added methods such as *add*, *remove*, *set*, *size*, etc. I've also added a simple **static** and **recursive** *sort* method, which accepts a Linked List reference as parameter, so that it can be used in the Main class being called as `sort(linkedList);` and it returns a sorted linked list.

The program throws **`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`**, at lines, `if (biggest.compareTo(nextNode.value) < 0) biggest = nextNode.value;` and `return sort(list);`. I want the sort method to sort the list in alphabetical order (my Linked List consists of String elements).

This is the method in code:

```
 /**
     * The sort method sorts the list in alphabetical order
     * @param list list to be sorted
     * @return sorted linked list
     */
static DD_RecursiveLinkedList sort(DD_RecursiveLinkedList list) {
        DD_Node nextNode = head.next;
        String biggest = head.value, smallest = tail.value; //by default biggest is the head, and smallest is the tail
        if (isEmpty()) return null; //if list is empty, return null
        do { //find the biggest and smallest value in the list
            if (biggest.compareTo(nextNode.value) < 0) biggest = nextNode.value; //if nextNode is bigger than the biggest, biggest is nextNode
            if (smallest.compareTo(nextNode.value) > 0) smallest = nextNode.value; //if nextNode is smaller than the smallest, smallest is nextNode
            nextNode = nextNode.next; //update nextNode
        } while (nextNode!=null); //loop until nextNode is null

        set(0, biggest); set(size()-1, smallest); //set biggest as the head of the list, and smallest as the tail
//        remove(biggest);//remove the biggest (head) from the list
//        remove(smallest); //remove the smallest (tail) from the list
//        list.add(0, biggest); //add the biggest to the sorted list as head element
//        list.add(size()-1, smallest); //add the smallest to the sorted list as tail element
        return sort(list); //sort the order of sorted list recursively
    }
```

---

I've commented out the `add` and `remove` lines, because they were included in the error so instead of `add` and `remove` methods, I've used the `set` method, to replace the element at the specified index with the specified element.

Comment: Firstly: dont sort recursively. It is a bad idea. You will hit max stack depth very quickly, even if your function is correct. Secondly: you stop recursion only if the list is empty, but you always look at the same list. This will crash even on tiny lists. Thirdly: finding biggest and smallest element is wrong. Look at list ["1","2"]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is , the sort(list) method is going to be called infinite number of time, causing the java stack to overflow and impossible to store any variables in stack further.

```
return sort(list);
```

1.**As there is no restriction saying at what conditions recursion should. Stop. It will keep on calling sort (). - this leading to stackOverflow error**

2.Since the remove() statements are commented. List size is not altered at all .So it will not stop at isEmpty check also. Also: bcoz whatever you list is it’s finally going to return null always.